# What are the types of event and context in gcloud Firestore triggers?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Google has an example of creating a trigger for Cloud Firestore:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore

```js
/**
 * Background Function triggered by a change to a Firestore document.
 *
 * @param {!Object} event The Cloud Functions event.
 * @param {!Object} context Cloud Functions event metadata.
 */
exports.helloFirestore = (event, context) => {
  const triggerResource = context.resource;

  console.log(`Function triggered by event on: ${triggerResource}`);
  console.log(`Event type: ${context.eventType}`);

  if (event.oldValue && Object.keys(event.oldValue).length) {
    console.log('\nOld value:');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event.oldValue, null, 2));
  }

  if (event.value && Object.keys(event.value).length) {
    console.log('\nNew value:');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event.value, null, 2));
  }
};
```

They only have this example in plain JavaScript, not TypeScript.

If using TypeScript, what are the types for `event` and `context` objects? And what package includes them?

This question is specifically regarding triggers deployable with `gcloud`, not Firebase triggers.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/write-event-driven-functions), for 1st gen functions use [Background functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/write-event-driven-functions#background-functions) for NodeJS and for 2nd gen use [CloudEvent functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/write-event-driven-functions#cloudevent-functions). Contents of `event` might differ depending on the trigger. Firebase's documentation does explain what [Event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/firebase-functions.event) and [EventContext](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/firebase-functions.eventcontext) are but I was not able to find the same in Google Cloud docs itself.